# user_access( ) - Printing list 'variables' you can plug into?

Tags: users

Something I have seen many times, but never fully understood is what exactly to plug into `user_access()` (Want to get the correct terminology here too, do you just call them variables?). I have seen some basic ones like `user_access('manager access')`, manager being a made user? Another using `user_access('access nodes links')`, which I assume is just seeing if they can see/access the tab links on a node.

If there an easy way to get a common list of what you can plug into user_access()?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the permissions on the /admin/people/permissions page.